# Angular RXJS 6: filter observable array for items matching object key

Tags: angular, filter, observable, rxjs6

I have a service that returns an array of objects as an observable, a list of countries with objects with the country name and three-letter code,
`countries$ = this.mockData.get('countries.json');`

If I have a 3-letter code for a country, I want to be able to filter the observable and return the matching name.  For example if I have "GBR" I want to return "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"

I have tried this,

```
  getfullCountryName() {
    const name = this.countries$.pipe(filter((c) => c.alpha3 === 'GBR'));
    console.log('name =', name);
    
    return name;
  }
```

but I must be forgetting something, since all I get in console is
`name =  Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: FilterOperator}`

What am I leaving off?

`countries$` is a type of Country

```
export interface Country {
  numeric: string;
  alpha2: string;
  alpha3: string;
  name: string;
}
```

where should I put the type `< >` in that expression to get typings. e.g. that `c` has an attribute `alpha3`

Comment: you have to subscribe ...

Comment: in your case, `filter` returns an observable and `name` receives an observable.

Comment: so I try this an still nothing `    const name = this.countries$.pipe(filter((c) => c.alpha3 === 'GBR')).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));`

Comment: console.log(x) should display the result that you are looking for.....

Answer (score 0):

**Filter** returns an **observable** in your case which gets assigned to **name**;

```
getfullCountryName() {
    const name = this.countries$.pipe(filter((c) => c.alpha3 === 'GBR'));
      
    return name;  // returns observable
}
```

somewhere

```
this.getfullCountryName().subscribe(result=>console.log(result));  // will print the right result.
```

---

better version,

```
 getfullCountryName() {
    return this.countries$.pipe(filter((c) => c.alpha3 === 'GBR'));
}
```